# Is it possible to send email using YQL?

Tags: email, yql

Is it possible to send Yahoo email (or any other free service like Google mail) using YQL?
If yes, please tell a little bit about the procedure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use YQL to talk to the [Yahoo! Mail Web Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/).  The mail web service uses OAuth for authentication and can communicate via JSON-RPC (or SOAP)  which is no problem in YQL.

Comment: do i to get the Yahoo App ID in order to send mail through YQL??

Comment: Yes, you will need your own App ID and use that through YQL.